# MongoDB add field after group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I currently have this:
[image]

But I'd like to add another field called totalSum (which is the sum of all sums) outside the group, so it's just included once, like this:

```
{
  [  
    {
      "_id": "Item1",
      "sum": 17
    },
    {
      "_id": "Item2",
      "sum": 8
    }
  ],
  totalSum: 25
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you either paste the text of what you currently have or, preferably, share the link to the playground example so that we don't have to manually recreate?

Answer (score 0):

You can add another group stage to get the total and also add another field with an array of the elements using `$addToSet`, adding the complete document to the set using the [$$ROOT variable](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#mongodb-variable-variable.ROOT)

```
{$group: {_id: null, totalSum: {$sum: "$sum"}, sums: $addToSet: "$$ROOT"}}}
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/inakKMBq9U9)